# OneDrive doesn't show proper icons

Tags: onedrive-for-business, file-icons

We are using SharePoint 2013 with OneDrive for Business.

We also use the inline records management feature that displays a lock-symbol on documents when flagged as record.

In the OneDrive however it still shows the normal icons w/o lock-symbol. Is there a way to make OneDrive display the proper icon?

Comment: I think you need to contact Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks, I (cross-)posted on msdn forum and will update this question accordingly